# Error:(100, 54) error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java, android, windows, debugging

This is code of file MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lstVideo;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> arrHinh= new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ArrayList<Video> arrVideo=new ArrayList<Video>();
    String playlistId="LL-5bWlJvcvfR...........";
    final String API_KEY="AIza............";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lstVideo=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstVideo);
        new ParseYoutube().execute();
    }
    private class ParseYoutube extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String time, urlHinh, title, idVideo;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (getJsonFromUrl() != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObbject = new JSONObject(getJsonFromUrl());
                    JSONArray jsonItems = jsonObbject.getJSONArray("items");
                    if (jsonItems.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonItems.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonItem = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject jsonsnippet = jsonItem.getJSONObject("snippet");
                            title = jsonsnippet.getString("title");
                            time = jsonsnippet.getString("publishedAt");
                            JSONObject jsonThum = jsonsnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                            JSONObject jsondefault = jsonThum.getJSONObject("default");
                            urlHinh = jsondefault.getString("url");
                            JSONObject jsonResource = jsonsnippet.getJSONObject("resourceId");
                            idVideo = jsonResource.getString("videoId");

                            Video video = new Video();
                            video.setTime(time);
                            video.setTitle(title);
                            video.setUrlID(idVideo);
                            arrVideo.add(video);

                            URL url = new URL(urlHinh);
                            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                            arrHinh.add(bm);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException | MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            lstVideo.setAdapter(new YoutubeAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrVideo, arrHinh));
        }
    }


    public String getJsonFromUrl() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=" + playlistId + "&key=" + API_KEY);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()!== null)
            {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is error in Message Tab:

> Error:(100, 54) error: illegal start of expression
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I don't know why I can not debug this app

Comment: Which line is line 100?  This part you've given us has only 97 lines.  If line 100 is `while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()!== null)`, then you've just mistyped the inequality check (`!=`, not `!==`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `while` loop in `getJsonFromUrl()` by -

```
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given extra = sign in line 77. change it. Replace it. Now your code will be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lstVideo;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> arrHinh= new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ArrayList<Video> arrVideo=new ArrayList<Video>();
    String playlistId="LL-5bWlJvcvfR...........";
    final String API_KEY="AIza............";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lstVideo=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstVideo);
        new ParseYoutube().execute();
    }
    private class ParseYoutube extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String time, urlHinh, title, idVideo;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (getJsonFromUrl() != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObbject = new JSONObject(getJsonFromUrl());
                    JSONArray jsonItems = jsonObbject.getJSONArray("items");
                    if (jsonItems.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonItems.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonItem = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject jsonsnippet = jsonItem.getJSONObject("snippet");
                            title = jsonsnippet.getString("title");
                            time = jsonsnippet.getString("publishedAt");
                            JSONObject jsonThum = jsonsnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                            JSONObject jsondefault = jsonThum.getJSONObject("default");
                            urlHinh = jsondefault.getString("url");
                            JSONObject jsonResource = jsonsnippet.getJSONObject("resourceId");
                            idVideo = jsonResource.getString("videoId");

                            Video video = new Video();
                            video.setTime(time);
                            video.setTitle(title);
                            video.setUrlID(idVideo);
                            arrVideo.add(video);

                            URL url = new URL(urlHinh);
                            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                            arrHinh.add(bm);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException | MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            lstVideo.setAdapter(new YoutubeAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrVideo, arrHinh));
        }
    }


    public String getJsonFromUrl() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=" + playlistId + "&key=" + API_KEY);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()!= null) // while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()!== null) you need to remove extra = sign
            {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Agree with  **childofsoong**.